# Concept that requires a function to return another concept by value or reference

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I'm learning C++ concepts. Now I can write a concept that requires the presence of a function which returns something that satisfies an other concept, but so far only by value (in function `getB()`).

Function `getC()` gives an error because: `because 'decltype(t.getC())' (aka 'const float &') does not satisfy 'floating_point'` and `because 'is_floating_point_v<const float &>' evaluated to false`. It is a reference after all.

```
template<typename T>
concept TestConcept =
    requires(T t)
    {
        {t.getA()} -> std::convertible_to<float>;
        {t.getB()} -> std::floating_point;
        {t.getC()} -> std::floating_point;
    };

struct CTest
{
    int a = 10.0f;

    const float& getA() const {return a;}

    const float  getB() const {return a;}
    
    //const float  getC() const {return a;} // This would be OK
    const float& getC() const {return a;} //ERROR
};
```

What I want from this concept is something like:

```
void func(const TestConcept auto& test){

    std::floating_point c = test.getC();

    //...
}
```

Basically to have a function that returns something that satisfies a concept like `std::floating_point` by reference or by value. Is it doable? Can something similar to `std::is_convertible` work there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a new concept that accepts floating point references, like so:

```
template<typename T>
concept FloatingPointReference = std::is_reference_v<T> && std::floating_point<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
```

Or if you don't care whether it returns by value or by reference you could check whether the decayed type adheres to the concept.

```
template<typename T>
concept DecaysToFloatingPoint = std::floating_point<std::decay_t<T>>;
```

These both accept mutable L value references however, so that is something to think about. You might want to write a concept that only accepts const reference and value for example.